# ssh KeyRegenerationInterval

Tags: ssh, sshd

Is KeyRegenerationInterval related to login with ssh-key?

KeyRegenerationInterval acts on server's private key.
Login with ssh-key acts on id_rsa and  id_rsa.pub.

Comment: I have learned that RSAAuthentication is for SSHv1 keys and PubkeyAuthentication is for SSHv2 keys.

Answer (score 1):

KeyRegenerationInterval is a setting for the obsolete SSH protocol version 1.

Furthermore, it does not concern *authentication keys*: it is about ephemeral *session keys*, which are generated for each individual SSH session, and regenerated mid-session if the session runs long enough (the default SSHv1 key regeneration interval used to be 3600 seconds, or one hour).

These keys were never stored on disk: the idea was that if an intruder gains root access on a server and captures the session keys by dumping `sshd`'s memory at one point of time, even if the intruder has recorded old SSH connections, the captured keys will only decrypt up to the last hour or so of the sessions that existed at point of key capture and no further.

The SSH protocol v1 has known design-level weaknesses and should not be used any longer. The protocol version 2 does things differently:  versions of OpenSSH that have been compiled to support v2 only won't have this setting at all.